# InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 154587 values, but the requested shape has 150528

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to write a tfrecords and read it, and I have already get ‘train.tfrecords’ file, but when I use this function to read it

```
image_size=224
def read_and_decode(filename,batch_size):
  filename_queue=tf.train.string_input_producer([filename])
  reader=tf.TFRecordReader()
  _,serialized_example=reader.read(filename_queue)#返回文件名和文件
  features=tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example,features={
    "label": tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.int64),
    "img_raw":tf.FixedLenFeature([],tf.string),
  })
  img=tf.decode_raw(features['img_raw'],tf.uint8)
  img=tf.cast(img,tf.float32)
  img=tf.reshape(img,[image_size,image_size,3])
  img = tf.random_crop(img, [image_size, image_size, 3])
  img = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(img)
  img=tf.image.per_image_standardization(img)
  label=tf.cast(features['label'],tf.int32)
  img_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([img, label],
                                                batch_size=batch_size,    num_threads=10, capacity=16 * batch_size,
                                                 min_after_dequeue=8*batch_size)
  label_batch= tf.reshape(label_batch, [batch_size, 1])
  indices = tf.reshape(tf.range(0, batch_size, 1), [batch_size, 1])
  label_batch = tf.sparse_to_dense(
    tf.concat(values=[indices, label_batch], axis=1),
    [batch_size, 3], 1.0, 0.0)
  assert len(img_batch.get_shape()) == 4
  assert img_batch.get_shape()[0] == batch_size
  assert img_batch.get_shape()[-1] == 3
  assert len(label_batch.get_shape()) == 2
  assert label_batch.get_shape()[0] == batch_size
  assert label_batch.get_shape()[1] == 3

  # Display the training images in the visualizer.
  tf.summary.image('images', img_batch)
  return img_batch, label_batch
```

The error is:

```
Caused by op 'Reshape', defined at:
File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/tensorflow/ResNet/main.py", line  176, in <module>tf.app.run()
File"C:\ProgramFiles\Python35\lib\sitepackages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
 File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/tensorflow/ResNet/main.py", line 169, in main
train(hps)
File "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/tensorflow/ResNet/main.py", line 31, in train
images, labels = read_and_decode('train.tfrecords', hps.batch_size)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\tensorflow\ResNet\input.py", line 15, in read_and_decode
img=tf.reshape(img,[image_size,image_size,3])
 File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 2510, in reshape
name=name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
self._traceback = _extract_stack()
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 154587 values, but the requested shape has 150528
 [[Node: Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Cast, Reshape/shape)]]
```

I searched on the internet for a while and I think the problem happens at these codes, but I don't know how to fix it, please help me,thank you

```
img=tf.decode_raw(features['img_raw'],tf.uint8)
img=tf.cast(img,tf.float32)
img=tf.reshape(img,[image_size,image_size,3])
```

Comment: Are you sure the records are 224×224×3 images and not 227×227×3 images? Try changing image_size to 227.

Comment: Oh...I didn't notice that,  I prepare TFRecords again and it works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can clearly see this in logs as explained by @Mathias Rav in comments.

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Input to reshape is a tensor with 154587 values, but the requested shape has 150528
```

Size of TFrecords is 154587 : 227x227x3

But, Size of tensor shape you provided is 150528 : 224x224x3

Check the required input size of the model first and adjust images accordingly.
Either,

1. Resize the image to 224x224x3 using tf.image.resize_images() or
2. Prepare TFRecords again with size 224x224x3 or
3. If model input size is 227x227x3, then just change the image_size to 227.

I hope this helps.

Comment: yes,I rewrite TFRecords and it works, thank you very much!